# Detect browser close or page change VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to detect when user change/insert into an input and he try to change/close page to give him a warning. I do some research but till now I didn't find anything.

```
<b-form-group label="Name" label-for="name-input">
<b-form-input
        id="name-input"
        v-model="name"
></b-form-input>
</b-form-group>

created() {
    document.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handlerClose)
},
handlerClose: function handler(event) {
    console.log('CHANGE!!!!');
},
```

Comment: That's two questions, please specify the one question you want to get help with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to simply compare the stringified JSON of your selected data. If they are equivalent, then we know that the data has not been changed/updated/mutated by the user.

Here's a simple setup:

1. Create a method that generates the JSON for the user data that you want to observe for changes.
2. When the compoonent/app is created, you cache the data that it is created with and store/cache it
3. Create a computed property that simply returns the current state of the user data and cached user data
4. In the beforeunload handler, you can then check the returned value of this computed property to determine of the user has mutated data or not.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  // COMPONENT DATA
  data: {
    // Dummy data
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    
    // Cache form data
    cachedFormData: null,
  },
  
  // COMPONENT LIFECYCLE HOOK
  created: function() {
    // Create a cache when component/app is created
    this.cachedFormData = this.formDataForComparison();
    
    document.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handlerClose);
  },
  
  // COMPUTED PROPERTIES
  computed: {
    // Compares cached user data to live data
    hasChanged() {
      return this.cachedFormData !== this.formDataForComparison();
    }
  },
  
  // COMPONENT METHODS
  methods: {
    // Callback handler
    handlerClose: function() {
      if (this.hasChanged) {
        // Logic when change is detected
        // e.g. you can show a confirm() dialog to ask if user wants to proceed
      } else {
        // Logic when no change is detected
      }
    },
    
    // Helper method that generates JSON for string comparison
    formDataForComparison: function() {
      return JSON.stringify({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="firstName" />
  <input type="text" v-model="lastName" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <span>Has user changed data? <strong>{{ hasChanged }}</strong></span>
</div>
```

---

An alternative method would be simply storing a flag that has a ground state of `false`, as proposed by the other answer. The flag state is switched to `true` wheneveran input/change event is detected on the element. However, there are several disadvantages associated with this method:

1. Even when the user undo his/her changes, it will still marked as changed. This constitutes a false positive.
2. You will need to either bind watchers to all the `v-model` members, or bind input/change event listeners to all input elements on the page. If your form is huge, there is a chance that you will forget to do this to an input element.

Answer (score 4):

## Detect navigating to a different page or close the page

You can try using the same eventhandler `beforeunload` on the window object, not the document object, as stated in the MDN Web Docs for example ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event ). The event should handle both cases, switching page and closing page.

```js
<script>
  export default {
    created() {

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
        // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
        event.returnValue = '';
      });

    }
  }
</script>
```

This event enables a web page to trigger a confirmation dialog asking the user if they really want to leave the page. If the user confirms, the browser navigates to the new page, otherwise it cancels the navigation.

#### About your second question to detect whetever changes has been made : This eventhandler does *not* detect changes.

In order to mantain a state whetever the user made a change, e.g. to a form, I would outsource this state with a data prop `isChanged` and initialize it with `false`. Then use Vue directives `v-on:change` or `v-on:input` to change the prop from `false` to `true`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" @change="userMadeChange" v-model="inputText" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputText : "",
      isChanged : false
    }
  },
  methods : {
    userMadeChange() {
      this.isChanged = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in Vue 3 with Typescript and Composition API.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form>
      <input type="text" v-model="firstName" />
      <input type="text" v-model="lastName" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Has user changed data? <strong>{{ hasChanged }}</strong></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted, onUnmounted, computed } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // COMPONENT DATA
    const firstName = ref('John');
    const lastName = ref('Doe');
    const cachedFormData = ref<string | null>(null);

    // COMPONENT LIFECYCLE HOOKS
    onMounted(() => {
      cachedFormData.value = formDataForComparison();
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleClose);
    });

    onUnmounted(() => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleClose);
    });

    // COMPUTED PROPERTIES
    const hasChanged = computed(() => {
      return cachedFormData.value !== formDataForComparison();
    });

    // COMPONENT METHODS
    function handleClose() {
      if (hasChanged.value) {
        // Logic when change is detected
        // e.g. you can show a confirm() dialog to ask if the user wants to proceed
      } else {
        // Logic when no change is detected
      }
    }

    function formDataForComparison() {
      return JSON.stringify({
        firstName: firstName.value,
        lastName: lastName.value,
      });
    }

    return {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      hasChanged,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```