# Value does not reset when browser go back clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have added code to reset when browser go back button clicked. Below is my code.

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 2) { // This is to check navigation back button
    $('#radiobtn_one').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radiobtn_two').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radiobtn_three').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radiobtn_four').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radiobtn_six').prop('checked',false);

}
```

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="radiobtn_one" value="active" 
v-bind:checked="status=='active'" v-model="status">
```

My form has 5 steps. All those radio button are in next steps, those are all hidden initially with vue js condition.

Can anyone explain how could i reset hidden (display:none via vue js) input radio buttons?

Comment: try to set the `this.status = ''` in vue code.

Comment: no it doesn't work, i have added it under created function

Comment: `v-show="false"`.  Also, generally speaking, don't use jQuery with Vue.  (There may be rare exceptions.)

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59410524/692331 by adding an event listener for the page unloading, you could uncheck the boxes before they even leave the page.  Also, instead of using jQuery, just set this.status = '' within the function callback.